# Windows XP cannot find the Windows TEMP folder using %temp% in the run command window

Tags: windows, shortcuts

please help me when i type %temp% in run it will show an error instead of temp folder.
The error is like as follows.
windows can't find %temp%.Make sure you typed the name correctly......
how to solve this issue........

Comment: Did you type `cd %temp%` ?

Comment: Uhm, it should work. You know, you just have to open Run, then type "%temp%", simply, without anything else. Did you copy-paste this from somewhere? There could be invisible characters or something. Try to type it out. If you don't want to look into this too deeply, you could just browse to C:\Users\<YOUR USER FOLDER>\AppData\Local\Temp, by typing it in Windows Explorer's address bar. Quite quick, too. Or just click your way to it. I'm not sure why you'd want to use Run to open a folder in the first place, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Those are environment variables, and they're set up in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings, then in the new window that appears, go to the Advanced tab.  At the bottom will be a little button that is labelled "Environmnet Variables..."

You will see User Variables (only applies to the current user) and System Variables ( all users) defined here.

You're likely missing the user variable for TEMP.  Click on New and and use TEMP as the variable name (no % characters) and in the variable value, type in the path you wish it to resolve to.

You might need to log out and log back in to get it to work via the Run menu.  I know if using a command prompt, you only need to close and restart the command prompt.

To see the value of your environment variable, in a command prompt, type:

```
echo %VAR_NAME%
```

If you see %VAR_NAME% echoed back at you, the environment variable has not been set.  Otherwise, it'll echo back what the variable resolves to.